# error TS: Property 'dataset' does not exists on type 'Element'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm getting this error in terminal, in the process of compilation in a angular8 environment. 
On the localhost I navigate the page without any problems and without any errors in console. 
I made a console.log of the variable that has assigned that dataset property, and it is read correctly.
Below there's the interested code part:

```
      let timelineEls = document.querySelectorAll('[data-scroll-timeline]');
  scroll.on("scroll", () => {
    for ( let i = 0; i < timelineEls.length; i++ ) {
      let progress = self.getProgress(timelineEls[i]);
      let timelineKey = timelineEls[i].dataset.scrollTimeline;

      console.log(timelineEls[i].dataset);

      let timeline = timelines[timelineKey]._recent;
      let timeline = timelines[timelineKey];
      let duration = timeline.duration();
      if ( progress > 0 && progress <= 1 ) {
        timeline.seek(progress * duration);
      } else {
        if ( progress <= 0 ) {
          timelines[timelineKey].seek(0);
        } else {
          timelines[timelineKey].seek(duration);
        }
      }
    }
  })
```

console.log stamps correctly this: DOMStringMap {scroll: "", scrollTimeline: "albed-anim"}

Do you have any idea of how to get rid of this error? I guess it's a typescript error but i couldn't find any reasons while it shows and how to avoid it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You shoud check if the dataset exists before referencing it. That should do the trick ;) Sometimes TS is annoying!

Comment: @AlexanderElert Hey, thank you for the fast answer. Could you explain me the correct way to check if dataset exists?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The property `dataset` does not exist on type `Element`, but does exist on `HTMLElement`. You need to make sure it's of this type before proceeding. It also works to adjust your for loop a bit:

```
for (const timelineEl of timelineEls) {
  if (timelineEl instanceof HTMLElement) {
    const progress = self.getProgress(timelineEl);
    const timelineKey = timelineEl.dataset.scrollTimeline;
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Or you could just cast it into HTMLElement. This is something i did a couple of times in the past, wokring with the dom. `if((timelineEls[i] as HTMLElement).dataset.scrollTimeline)`

Comment: Thank you to the both of you. Putting the if condition didn't make the error go, but i declared the variable value with the HTMLElement typing as you told me. So now it's `let timelineKey = (timelineEls[i] as HTMLElement).dataset.scrollTimeline;` and i'm encountering no problems during compilations.

Comment: @AlexanderElert in certain conditions that could fail, if for instance the `NodeList` contains an element that is not an `HTMLElement`. With `instanceof` you will not have this issue

Comment: @AriannaF the reason it didn't work for you, is because you are using the `[i]` index accessor. If you call `timelineEls[i]` once, it does not necessarily mean that the 2nd time you call it, it will return the same element. So that's why I changed the for loop to be a `for of` loop. You will not have this compiler issue